# Problem with JWT authentication in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with JWT authentication using django-rest-knox.

**Error is:** `Detail: Authentication credentials were not provided.`

**ENDPOINT:** `/api/auth/login/`

**Headers in the POST request to the endpoint:** 
`{
     Content-Type: application/json
 }`

**body:**

```
{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": 1234
}
```

**Login API View:**

```
class UserLoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user,
                                   context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": token
        })
```

**Serializer:**

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()


    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid Credentials")
```

**Default Settings:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to authorize django-rest-knox login path without 401 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828599/how-to-authorize-django-rest-knox-login-path-without-401-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your procedure is wrong. According to Knox documents, You need to give an access permission login endpoint. But you did not give permission to access your login endpoint. 
So your login endpoint looks like this,

```
# views.py 
from django.contrib.auth import login
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from knox.views import LoginView as KnoxLoginView

class LoginView(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(LoginView, self).post(request, format=None)

# settings.py 
REST_KNOX = {
  'USER_SERIALIZER': 'knox.serializers.UserSerializer',
}
```

If you use the user serializer in your setting you get token with the username of the requesting user like bellow

```
{"user":{"username":"admin"},"token":"00bd2a5e517800b75a8f36bbf3baea4c839169108b25a5a5ea599a4ecda974c0"}
```

More details here. [Knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox/blob/master/docs/auth.md)

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems that you are using knox which is not exactly the same, but in essence it is similar. Your view seems protected probably because of your `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` settings.

If you to be able to login via this view you'd have to set

```
permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
```

on your view.

However I would not do that since this is a hack. (I know I have been through it and we red the same article).

The correct way to do it is to define the User serializer in the Django Configuration/Settings file, so that you can retrieve the info you want when you log in.

```
REST_KNOX = {
    'USER_SERIALIZER': 'auth.serializers.UserRetrieveSerializer'
}
```

Then simply extend the default login view and use `basic auth` as authentication class.

```
from knox.views import LoginView as KnoxLoginView
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class LoginAPI(KnoxLoginView):
    """
    Login endpoint.
    """
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
```

And for all the other views you could use `knox.auth.TokenAuthentication`.
And that's it...

Relevant code for testing it is:

```
import base64

def get_basic_auth_header(username, password):
    return 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(
        ('%s:%s' % (username, password)).encode('ascii')).decode()

 from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

 class MyTestCase(APITestCase):
     username = 'foo'
     password = 'bar'

     def test_login(self):
         # Add basic auth credentials
         self.client.credentials(
             HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=get_basic_auth_header(
                 self.username, self.password))
         etc...
```

In your `urls.py`

```py
from knox import views as knox_views
from .views import LoginAPI

...
    url(r'^login/$', LoginAPI.as_view(), name='knox_login'),                    
    url(r'^logout/$', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout'),     
    url(r'^logoutall/$', knox_views.LogoutAllView.as_view(), name='knox_logoutall'),
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I added permission_classes = [AllowAny, ] but nothing changed. I've tested before.

Comment: yes you actually needed both, extend KnoxLoginView and add AllowAny.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Did you register your view in the urls.py file? Do you need a code snippet for basic auth in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get your error "credentials were not provided"? If it is the case when calling the route by hand in the browser, I think it is fine (at least I get it, while data is loaded properly in my tables etc.)

I had the problem that authentication with knox token did not work on Safari and on iPad. The reason was that I had a trailing slash in my routes and this caused 301 - Moved permanently responses with subsequent redirects, which obviously did not forward the token. I removed the trailing slashes and everything was fine then.

By the way: Using

```
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
```

does not seem to be right, I think it more or less contradicts the use of tokens. It should be

```
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are deeploying to the Apache then add the WSGIPassAuthorization On to the 000-default.conf file. That solved my issues. See: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/